# Proper way of assigning variables

Tags: php, variables, variable-assignment

Can someone please introduce a more efficient or proper way of assigning variables in php?

Here is a snippet of my code:

class PurchaseController extends BaseController
{

```
/**
*Gets input form form
*
*@var input
*/

protected $input;

public function postPurchaseCheck()
{   
    $input = Input::all();
    $this->input = $input;
```

if form submit button has value "buy" then use postPurhcase method

```
    if (Input::get('buy')) {
        $this->postPurchase();
    }
    elseif (Input::get('cart')) {
        $this->postAddCart();
    }

}

public function postAddCart()
{
    //Add these items to cart
    echo "Add these items to cart";

    $memory = $this->input['memory'];
    $color = $this->input['color'];
    $size = $this->input['size'];
    $price = $this->input['price'];
    $battery = $this->input['battery'];
    $accessories = $this->input['accessories'];
```

.........etc

```
}

public function postPurchase()
{
    //Get prices, item id, etc and send user to checkout page
    $memory = $this->input['memory'];
    $color = $this->input['color'];
    $size = $this->input['size'];
    $price = $this->input['price'];
    $battery = $this->input['battery'];
    $accessories = $this->input['accessories'];
```

.........and so forth. I was wondering if there is a faster way of doing this in php without having to reassign variables for each method
    }
}

Comment: There's no obvious reason for you to be making local variables for every input this way. Why not just use the values directly from `$this->input`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like the following code, will save a few lines...

```
<?php 
//loop an expected array, check and set from input
foreach(array('memory','color','size','price','...') as $key){
    $$key = isset($this->input[$key]) ? $this->input[$key] : null;
}
?>
```

`$$key` = http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

But you may as well use `$this->input['memory']` ect, instead of reassigning them to local variables.

Also your doing, which is basically just wasting memory (same as above):

```
$input = Input::all();
$this->input = $input;
```

Just do: `$this->input = Input::all();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extract method but I would be cautious about this function with input. Pretty much you will be putting yourself back to Register globals.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Why can't use the value directly from the input?